# What is the font used in this document (Metropolis Doc)?

Tags: fonts

The Metropolis Beamer theme uses Fira Sans by default, but I'm unsure whether its [documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive//Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamertheme-metropolis/metropolistheme.pdf) is using the same font. When I try to load Fira Sans into my own documents, they do not look like that.

For reference, I'm attaching the desired and actual fonts below. I'm using `\usepackage[sfdefault,lining]{FiraSans}` in my document.

**Metropolis**

[image: Metro]

**Mine**

[image: Mine]

Comment: Using the methods described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/82917 you can find out that it is FiraSans Light. Add the option `light` to `\usepackage`.

Comment: @campa Thank you. This does definitely help. I didn't know there could even exist tools for extracting fonts from pdfs, thanks, I'll check into that. I imagined it was Fira Sans but I couldn't find the appropriate options to pass to the package. I *just* noticed it's in the readme of the package though (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fira). Thanks

Comment: @campa Just a quick question though. The document does look closer to what I'm looking for after adding the ```light``` option. However, I noticed that mine looks a bit more "packed", while in the reference above the characters have a bit more space between them. How is this achieved?

Comment: You mean spacing *between* words? Well, that of course depends on the paragraph, spaces can be stretched. If I type 'A good presentation' in FiraSansLight 10pt I get obviously a slightly different interword spacing, but the words themselves are superimposable.

Comment: @campa I meant characters, but this could be just my perception as I feel my output was a bit more "condensed", or "packed". This is probably not the case though. Thanks for the answer, it did address my question. Feel free to post as answer so that I can close this (else I will choose to close based on the suggestion of the linked question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is available with your TeX installation. The fonts in the theme are defined as:

```
  \iffontsavailable{Fira Sans Light,%
                    Fira Sans Light Italic,%
                    Fira Sans,%
                    Fira Sans Italic}%
  {%
    \setsansfont[ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic},%
                 BoldFont={Fira Sans},%
                 BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic}]%
                {Fira Sans Light}%
  }{%
    \iffontsavailable{Fira Sans Light OT,%
                      Fira Sans Light Italic OT,%
                      Fira Sans OT,%
                      Fira Sans Italic OT}%
    {%
      \setsansfont[ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic OT},%
                   BoldFont={Fira Sans OT},%
                   BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic OT}]%
                  {Fira Sans Light OT}%
    }{%
      \PackageWarning{beamerthememetropolis}{%
        Could not find Fira Sans fonts%
      }
    }
  }
```

And in the documents source it is nearly the same as:

```
  \iffontsavailable{Fira Sans Light,%
                Fira Sans Light Italic,%
                Fira Sans,%
                Fira Sans Italic}{%
    \setmainfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans}]{Fira Sans Light}%
  }{%
    \iffontsavailable{Fira Sans Light OT,%
                  Fira Sans Light Italic OT,%
                  Fira Sans OT,%
                  Fira Sans Italic OT}{%
      \setmainfont[BoldFont={Fira Sans OT}]{Fira Sans Light OT}%
    }{%
      \typeout{%
        Could not find Fira Sans fonts. Creating documentation%
        with standard fonts.%
      }
    }
  }
  \iffontsavailable{Fira Mono, Fira Mono Bold}{%
    \setmonofont{Fira Mono}%
  }{%
    \iffontsavailable{Fira Mono OT, Fira Mono Bold OT}{%
      \setmonofont{Fira Mono OT}%
    }{%
      \typeout{%
        Could not find Fira Sans fonts. Creating documentation%
        with standard monospaced fonts.%
      }
    }
  }
}{
  \typeout{%
    You need to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to use the Fira fonts.%
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the source code for the Metropolis theme itself, not the source code of the documentation pdf, which is what I'm interested in. It turns out it's the same font however, I was missing the ```light``` option. I'm still struggling with getting the same space between characters though.

Comment: sure, but it uses the same definitions for the font settings. Have a look into the documents source!

Comment: I see you updated the answer. How did you find the source code for the documentation?

Comment: As I already wrote, it is part of your TeX distribution: `kpsewhich metropolistheme.dtx`  shows `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/source/latex/beamertheme-metropolis/metropolistheme.dtx`  on. my system.

Comment: I didn't know the source code of **documentations** were in the TeX distribution. That's a great fact to know, thanks!