# Bold font in Metropolis looks too heavy

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamer-metropolis

I use `\usepackage[sfdefault,light,lining]{FiraSans}` to reproduce the default font of the Beamer Metropolis theme. I followed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620366/what-is-the-font-used-in-this-document-metropolis-doc) question for this.

However, the bold font looks too heavy. When I comment the `\usepackage` line, the font changes. The default font of Metropolis is different. I obtain these results with Overleaf and TeXstudio. It seems that I need to add another option to `\usepackage` or change the options there. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[t,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

% Metropolis default font below? Bold font looks too heavy
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,lining]{FiraSans} 

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Information for the footer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of the slide, $\alpha$, $\gamma$}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item text
    \item Item text
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the bold font for title using `fontspec` package.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{metropolis}

% Metropolis default font below? Bold font looks too heavy
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,lining]{FiraSans} 

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Information for the footer}

\newfontfamily{\titlefont}{FiraSans}[%
    BoldFont = FiraSans-Medium.otf,
]
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\titlefont}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title of the slide, $\alpha$, $\gamma$}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item text
            \item Item text
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

Actually, it turns out the option `medium` does exactly the same thing! It uses medium font for `\bfseries`.

```tex
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{metropolis}

% Metropolis default font below? Bold font looks too heavy
\usepackage[sfdefault,light,medium,lining]{FiraSans} 

\setbeamertemplate{frame footer}{Information for the footer}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Title of the slide, $\alpha$, $\gamma$}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Item text
            \item Item text
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I included the lines as you suggested and I receive the error messages "Package fontspec Error: The font "FiraSans" cannot be found," "Package fontspec Error: The font "FiraSans-Medium.otf" cannot be found," and "Font TU/FiraSans(12)/b/n/12=FiraSans-Medium.otf at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found." I downloaded `FiraSans-Medium.otf` to the directory of the main tex file, but it does not change the error messages.

Comment: I get the same error when I use `xelatex`. Can you try using `lualatex`? I didn't have a problem with that.

Comment: Yes, it works with `lualatex`. Thank you. The font, however, is bold-regular: `BoldFont = FiraSans-Regular.otf` (not medium).

Comment: This solution is fine, but if you happen to know the option to use in `\usepackage[sfdefault,light,lining]{FiraSans}` to have the section titles behave in the expected way, it will be appreciated

Comment: @Andre, turns out it is possible. See my edit.

Comment: This is good, thanks. Now I found the additional options. It turns out that `medium` gets closer, but the default font for bold is regular. But it is close enough. Thanks!